# Why can't this initializer-list match to a template argument?

Tags: c++, templates, c++17, initializer-list, template-argument-deduction

```
#include <iostream>

class Foo
{
public:

    template <typename Container>
    Foo (const Container & args)
    {
        for (auto arg : args)
            std::cout << "ARG(" << arg << ")\n";
    }
};

int main ()
{
    Foo foo ({"foo", "bar", "baz"});
}
```

The error (using `g++ -std=c++17`) is

```
error: no matching function for call to ‘Foo::Foo(<brace-enclosed initializer list>)’
```

This works

```
Foo foo (std::vector<const char*> ({"foo", "bar", "baz"}));
```

Why can't the initializer-list match the template constructor?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`{"foo", "bar", "baz"}` has no type, so it cannot be deduced for

```
template <typename Container>
Foo (const Container&);
```

You can only use it for deduction for

```
template <typename T>
Foo (const std::initializer_list<T>&);
```

Answer (score 1):

As explained by Jarod42, `{"foo", "bar", "baz"}` has no type, so it cannot be deduced for `template <typename Container> Foo (const Container&)`.

Another possible solution is

```
template <typename T, std::size_t N>
Foo (T const (& arr)[N])
{
    for (auto arg : arr)
        std::cout << "ARG(" << arg << ")\n";
}
```

so `{"foo", "bar", "baz"}` is deduced as an initialization list for a C-style array with the correct size (3).